# Sorting hierarchical SQL rows based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I'm using the following SQL to generate hierarchical data and struggling to work out how I can get children to sort by the sort order ID value. Any advice on how would be appreciated. Note that this is not my SQL, it's taken from OpenCart's Category listing page which I've modified. I've tried adding the sort order to a few places, but doesn't seem to make any difference. The output I want is to show is

```
| PAGE_ID |                       NAME | PARENT_ID | SORT_ORDER |
|---------|----------------------------|-----------|------------|
|      75 |                     Index4 |         0 |         -7 |
|      60 |                      Index |         0 |          0 |
|      68 |             Index  >  Sub6 |        60 |         -6 |
|      61 |             Index  >  Sub1 |        60 |          1 |
|      65 | Index  >  Sub1  >  SubSub2 |        61 |          4 |
|      64 | Index  >  Sub1  >  SubSub1 |        61 |          6 |
|      67 |             Index  >  Sub5 |        60 |          1 |
|      62 |             Index  >  Sub2 |        60 |          2 |
|      63 |             Index  >  Sub3 |        60 |          5 |
|      69 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub3 |        63 |          1 |
|      71 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub5 |        63 |          2 |
|      72 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub4 |        63 |          5 |
|      70 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub6 |        63 |          9 |
|      66 |             Index  >  Sub4 |        60 |          7 |
|      74 |                     Index3 |         0 |          1 |
|      73 |                     Index2 |         0 |          4 |
```

Notice that each child subset of the tree is ordered individually based on the `sort_order` column, so the sort order for the `Index` will have no influence on `Sub1`, `Sub2` or `Sub3` and none of those will have an effect on `SubSub1`, `SubSub2` or `SubSub3`

[Here's the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a541a3/1)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oc_page`;
CREATE TABLE `oc_page` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `oc_page` VALUES ('60', '0', '0', '1', '2014-10-16 02:49:41', '2014-10-17 02:03:15'), ('61', '60', '1', '1', '2014-10-17 02:03:02', '2014-10-17 03:17:20'), ('62', '60', '2', '1', '2014-10-17 02:18:59', '2014-10-17 03:16:20'), ('63', '60', '3', '1', '2014-10-17 02:23:27', '2014-10-17 03:16:49'), ('64', '61', '6', '1', '2014-10-17 03:17:49', '2014-10-17 03:17:58'), ('65', '61', '4', '1', '2014-10-17 03:18:36', '2014-10-17 03:18:36');
COMMIT;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oc_page_description`;
CREATE TABLE `oc_page_description` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `oc_page_description` VALUES ('60', '1', 'Index', '&lt;p&gt;Test&lt;/p&gt;', 'Test', '', ''), ('61', '1', 'Sub1', 'Sub1', 'Sub1', '', ''), ('64', '1', 'SubSub1', 'SubSub1', 'SubSub1', '', ''), ('65', '1', 'SubSub2', 'SubSub2', 'SubSub2', '', ''), ('62', '1', 'Sub2', 'Sub2', 'Sub2', '', ''), ('63', '1', 'Sub3', 'Sub3', 'Sub3', '', '');
COMMIT;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oc_page_path`;
CREATE TABLE `oc_page_path` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`path_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `oc_page_path` VALUES ('60', '60', '0'), ('61', '61', '1'), ('61', '60', '0'), ('62', '62', '1'), ('62', '60', '0'), ('63', '63', '1'), ('63', '60', '0'), ('64', '64', '2'), ('64', '60', '0'), ('64', '61', '1'), ('65', '60', '0'), ('65', '61', '1'), ('65', '65', '2');
COMMIT;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `oc_page_to_store`;
CREATE TABLE `oc_page_to_store` (
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`,`store_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `oc_page_to_store` VALUES ('60', '0'), ('61', '0'), ('62', '0'), ('63', '0'), ('64', '0'), ('65', '0');
COMMIT;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT pp.page_id AS page_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pd1.name
                    ORDER BY pp.level SEPARATOR '  &gt;  ') AS name,
       p1.parent_id,
       p1.sort_order
FROM oc_page_path pp
LEFT JOIN oc_page p1 ON (pp.page_id = p1.page_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_page p2 ON (pp.path_id = p2.page_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_page_description pd1 ON (pp.path_id = pd1.page_id)
LEFT JOIN oc_page_description pd2 ON (pp.page_id = pd2.page_id)
WHERE pd1.language_id = '1'
  AND pd2.language_id = '1'
GROUP BY pp.page_id
ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a541a3/1/0)**:

Note: This is dummy data I've added to clarify the question more. The fiddle will show significantly less data

```
| PAGE_ID |                       NAME | PARENT_ID | SORT_ORDER |
|---------|----------------------------|-----------|------------|
|      60 |                      Index |         0 |          0 |
|      61 |             Index  >  Sub1 |        60 |          1 |
|      64 | Index  >  Sub1  >  SubSub1 |        61 |          6 |
|      65 | Index  >  Sub1  >  SubSub2 |        61 |          4 |
|      62 |             Index  >  Sub2 |        60 |          2 |
|      63 |             Index  >  Sub3 |        60 |          5 |
|      69 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub3 |        63 |          1 |
|      70 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub6 |        63 |          9 |
|      71 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub5 |        63 |          2 |
|      72 | Index  >  Sub3  >  SubSub4 |        63 |          5 |
|      66 |             Index  >  Sub4 |        60 |          7 |
|      67 |             Index  >  Sub5 |        60 |          1 |
|      68 |             Index  >  Sub6 |        60 |         -6 |
|      73 |                     Index2 |         0 |          4 |
|      74 |                     Index3 |         0 |          1 |
|      75 |                     Index4 |         0 |         -7 |
```

Comment: I've got no problem with a downvote, but I wish people would at least comment as to what needs improving before doing so

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a subquery to divorce the display `ORDER` from the inside `ORDER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT pp.page_id AS page_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(pd1.name
                          ORDER BY pp.level SEPARATOR '  >  ') AS name,
             p1.parent_id,
             p1.sort_order
      FROM oc_page_path pp
      LEFT JOIN oc_page p1 ON (pp.page_id = p1.page_id)
      LEFT JOIN oc_page p2 ON (pp.path_id = p2.page_id)
      LEFT JOIN oc_page_description pd1 ON (pp.path_id = pd1.page_id)
      LEFT JOIN oc_page_description pd2 ON (pp.page_id = pd2.page_id)
      WHERE pd1.language_id = '1'
        AND pd2.language_id = '1'
      GROUP BY pp.page_id
      ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,20
        ) sub
ORDER BY Sort_Order
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bdf5f/9/0)

Note:  I assume you need the inside `ORDER BY` due to the `LIMIT`, because if not you could just `ORDER BY Sort_Order`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will work. Basically each level of the hierarchy needs to be sorted based on the `sort_order` and `parent_id`. I've updated the question to give a better example. Also, the limit here is irrelevant

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow the ordering logic, the only difference between your desired and your current are 65 and 64 are switched, but why?

Comment: I was trying to figure it, it could be a situation where you need to use some conditional aggregates to get the sorting fields, but looking at all the relevant fields ungrouped I'm not seeing the reasoning behind the desired order, if you can expand on that a bit I'm sure we can get it.

Comment: Hi. OK, so the data is a list of pages, where each page has a parent page. Index is level 0 of the tree (or the trunk if you like(, Sub1, Sub2 and Sub3 are level 1 or the branches and SubSub1 and SubSub2 are level 2 or the final leaves (though in theory these could have elements of their own below them at level 3 etc. I've updated to give a better data set (in theory, haven't added to a fiddle) and as you can see, sorting occurs at each level independently of the level above. Sorry, this is harder to explain than I hoped :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can chop of the last part of the name, order by that first and then order by sort_order:

```
select page_id, parent_id, sort_order, name
     , substr(name, 1, length(name) - locate(' > ', reverse(name))) as path 
from (
    SELECT pp.page_id AS page_id
         , GROUP_CONCAT(pd1.name ORDER BY pp.level SEPARATOR '  >  ') AS name
         , p1.parent_id, p1.sort_order 
    FROM oc_page_path pp 
    LEFT JOIN oc_page p1 
        ON pp.page_id = p1.page_id 
    LEFT JOIN oc_page p2 
        ON pp.path_id = p2.page_id 
    LEFT JOIN oc_page_description pd1 
        ON pp.path_id = pd1.page_id 
    LEFT JOIN oc_page_description pd2 
        ON pp.page_id = pd2.page_id '
    WHERE pd1.language_id = '1'   
      AND pd2.language_id = '1' 
    GROUP BY pp.page_id, p1.parent_id, p1.sort_order
) as t 
order by path, sort_order;

+---------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
| page_id | parent_id | sort_order | name                       | path              |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
|      60 |         0 |          0 | Index                      | Index             |
|      61 |        60 |          1 | Index  >  Sub1             | Index  >          |
|      62 |        60 |          2 | Index  >  Sub2             | Index  >          |
|      63 |        60 |          3 | Index  >  Sub3             | Index  >          |
|      65 |        61 |          4 | Index  >  Sub1  >  SubSub2 | Index  >  Sub1  > |
|      64 |        61 |          6 | Index  >  Sub1  >  SubSub1 | Index  >  Sub1  > |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Lennart. Please take a look at the update I've made and the comments on the answer by Goat CO. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so what you need is a Depth First Search (DFS) where the siblings are sorted according to sort order. I don't see how that is possible (without changing the model). To get a DFS given the model you typically need the full name to sort by, that way children will be sorted directly after there parent. But then the sort order wont have any effect. As an additional note, make sure that each level have the same length. Otherwise the sorting will break. Sorry for not being able to help.

Comment: OK thanks anyway Lennart, appreciate your time and trying to help